# Getting html content of an adminhtml template is empty

Tags: magento-1

This is my code from my controller:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_pdf_invoice')
->setData('invoice', "mydata")
->setTemplate('mynamespace_mymodule/pdf/invoice.phtml');
```

This is my block content:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Myblock_Block_Adminhtml_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
//methods
}
```

I am trying to get the value of a template and put the content in a pdf file using the toHtml function. In my case:

```
$block->toHtml()
```

which is empty for some reason.

This is the path of my template:

```
.modman/Mynamespace_Mymodule/src/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mynamespace_mymodule/pdf/invoice.phtml
```

My first thought was about the symlinks. There are enabled from system/configuration and the modman files are deployed.

Why the content of the toHtml function is empty ? What should I check more ?

Thx in advance !

**[UPDATE]** 
I make a var_dump($block). and this is part of it:

```
...
["_allowSymlinks":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_template":protected]=>
  string(29) "mynamespace_mymodule/pdf/invoice.phtml"
.....
```

I'm not sure why the allowSymlinks has the value NULL.

Comment: pls check my answer and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$block = $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_pdf_invoice')
->setData('invoice', "mydata")
->setTemplate('mynamespace_mymodule/pdf/invoice.phtml');
```

Should be :

```
$block = $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_pdf_invoice')
->setData('invoice', "mydata")
->setTemplate('mynamespace_mymodule/pdf/invoice.phtml');
```

Comment: I got this: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() . The fact that if i make a syntax error in my block I got the syntax message error. So it gets to my block. The problem is with my phtml file somehow, I guess.

Comment: If i use you solution I got an error message as I said before. : )